# Apply a function (tf.square()) to some values of a Tensor - TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's start with an example. I have a tensor with shape of `[3, 3, 3]` like this

```
input = tf.constant([[[1.2, -2.3, 4.5], [1.03, 2.89, -1.2], [2.1, 1.9, -1.5]],
                     [[1.3, -2.4, 4.6], [1.04, 2.88, -1.3], [2.2, 1.8, -1.6]],
                     [[1.4, -2.5, 4.7], [1.05, 2.87, -1.4], [2.3, 1.7, -1.7]]],
                    dtype=tf.float32)
```

and I want to apply `tf.square` only to the elements lower than `2` for example.
What I'm doing is this

```
indices = tf.where(input <= 2)
base = tf.zeros_like(input)
ones = tf.constant(1, shape=[18])
mask = tf.scatter_nd(indices, ones, tf.cast(tf.shape(base), indices.dtype))
mask = tf.cast(mask, tf.float32)
masked = tf.square(tf.multiply(input, mask))
neg_mask = 1 - mask
neg_masked = tf.multiply(input, neg_mask)
output = tf.add(masked, neg_masked)
```

and it works. The final output is this

```
output = tf.constant([[[1.44, 5.29, 4.5], [1.0609, 2.89, 1.44], [2.1, 3.61, 2.25]],
                      [[1.69, 5.76, 4.6], [1.0816, 2.88, 1.69], [2.2, 3.24, 2.56]],
                      [[1.96, 6.25, 4.7], [1.1025, 2.87, 1.96], [2.3, 2.89, 2.89]]],
                     dtype=tf.float32)
```

The problem is that it's quite tricky because this is a toy example but in my case, the tensor has a shape of thousands of elements. Moreover as you can see in this line `ones = tf.constant(1, shape=[18])` I have coded `18` because I know that they are 18 and if I try to use for example `ones = tf.constant(1, shape=[indices.get_shape()[0]])` I get this error `TypeError: long returned non-long (type NoneType)`.

So my two questions are:

1. How can I solve this problem of the shape?
2. Is there a faster and more efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance

---

**edit**

Question 1 solved doing this `ones = tf.ones(shape=[tf.shape(indices)[0]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing is to square all values and then select the right ones:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input = tf.constant([[[1.2, -2.3, 4.5], [1.03, 2.89, -1.2], [2.1, 1.9, -1.5]],
                     [[1.3, -2.4, 4.6], [1.04, 2.88, -1.3], [2.2, 1.8, -1.6]],
                     [[1.4, -2.5, 4.7], [1.05, 2.87, -1.4], [2.3, 1.7, -1.7]]],
                    dtype=tf.float32)
output = tf.where(input < 2, tf.square(input), input)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(output))
```

Output:

```
[[[1.44      5.29      4.5      ]
  [1.0609    2.89      1.44     ]
  [2.1       3.61      2.25     ]]

 [[1.6899998 5.76      4.6      ]
  [1.0816    2.88      1.6899998]
  [2.2       3.2399998 2.5600002]]

 [[1.9599999 6.25      4.7      ]
  [1.1024998 2.87      1.9599999]
  [2.3       2.89      2.89     ]]]
```

If you had a really big tensor where only few values will be squared then you could consider squaring only the necessary values. I'm not sure this could ever be actually faster, though, since it requires some additional work and intermediate values, but you could benchmark it. If, instead of just squaring, you were doing a particularly expensive operation, I guess it could make a difference. This is more or less the same you did but a bit simpler:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input = tf.constant([[[1.2, -2.3, 4.5], [1.03, 2.89, -1.2], [2.1, 1.9, -1.5]],
                     [[1.3, -2.4, 4.6], [1.04, 2.88, -1.3], [2.2, 1.8, -1.6]],
                     [[1.4, -2.5, 4.7], [1.05, 2.87, -1.4], [2.3, 1.7, -1.7]]],
                    dtype=tf.float32)
m = input < 2
v = tf.boolean_mask(input, m)
v2 = tf.square(v)
v2_scatter = tf.scatter_nd(tf.where(m), v2, tf.cast(tf.shape(input), tf.int64))
output = input * tf.cast(~m, input.dtype) + v2_scatter
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(output))
    # Output is the same as before
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed the other parameters of the `tf.where()`. Thanks also for the other implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easier but not necessarily faster implementation:

```
input = tf.constant([[[1.2, -2.3, 4.5], [1.03, 2.89, -1.2], [2.1, 1.9, -1.5]],
                     [[1.3, -2.4, 4.6], [1.04, 2.88, -1.3], [2.2, 1.8, -1.6]],
                     [[1.4, -2.5, 4.7], [1.05, 2.87, -1.4], [2.3, 1.7, -1.7]]],
                    dtype=tf.float32)

original_shape = input.get_shape()
input = tf.reshape(input, shape=[-1])
output = tf.map_fn(lambda e:tf.cond(e < 2, lambda:tf.square(e), lambda:e), input)
output = tf.reshape(output, shape=original_shape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(output))
```

Output:

```
[[[1.44      5.29      4.5      ]
  [1.0609    2.89      1.44     ]
  [2.1       3.61      2.25     ]]

 [[1.6899998 5.76      4.6      ]
  [1.0816    2.88      1.6899998]
  [2.2       3.2399998 2.5600002]]

 [[1.9599999 6.25      4.7      ]
  [1.1024998 2.87      1.9599999]
  [2.3       2.89      2.89     ]]]
```

The `tf.map_fn(fn, elems, ...)` function unpacks the N-dimensional input `elems` along the first dimension into multiple N-1-dimensional subtensors and applies `fn` to each subtensor. So I reshape input into one-dimensional tensor, apply function on each element, and then reshape output to original shape.